# AD Account creation failure for names/addresses having alphanumerics

Tags: c#, exchange-server

While performing queries against Active Directory Domain Services using one  of the .NETs’ reference/namespace i.e., System.DirectoryServices, we are unable to create AD account containing numeric(s) in Display Name or Email Address.  It’s a 2 step process, creating the mailbox and then updating all the other attributes. While creating the mailbox we are not getting any error, however while updating the attributes to the same mailbox we are getting an custom error as mailbox / sAMAccountName doesn’t exist.

We are using the same DC throughout the code. Moreover, the code is working fine if the proposing display name and email address doesn’t have numeric(s). **Since the Exchange 2016 servers have been upgraded to CU8, we are facing this issue.**
We are using the .NET code instead of Exchange to avoid manual intervention. It’s integrated with other systems to auto generate the mail boxes and AD accounts.
It’s a 2 step process because we can’t pass all the other attributes to the New-Mailbox cmdlet. Once the mailbox gets created, we are updating it with the other attributes.

In Event Viewer, the object was created, modified & finally deleted. The deletion is happening automatically  which is exceptional.

**Code Snippet**

```
//Creating mailbox
DirectorySearcher dSearchUPN = new DirectorySearcher(deCon);
dSearchUPN.Filter = "(UserPrincipalName=" + strUserPrincipalName + ")";
SearchResult sResultUPN = dSearchUPN.FindOne();
if (sResultUPN == null)
{
                                //Open it
                                runspace.Open();

                                using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
                                {
                                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                                    powershell.AddCommand("New-Mailbox");

                                    powershell.AddParameter("Name", strName);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("UserPrincipalName", strUserPrincipalName);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("Alias", strAlias);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("PrimarySmtpAddress", strPrimarySmtpAddress);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("OrganizationalUnit", strOrganizationalUnit);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("Database", strDatabase);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("SamAccountName", strSamAccountName);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("Password", strPassword);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("ResetPasswordOnNextLogon", true);
                                    powershell.AddParameter("DomainController", "ABCDWXYZADC2.corp.cyient.com");
                                    powershell.Invoke();
}

//Logic for Display Name & Email Address for duplicate First Name & Last Name
int i = 1;

while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchEmailAddress(strPrimarySmtpAddress)))
{
i = i + 1;

strName = dr["firstName"].ToString().Replace(".", "") + " " + dr["lastName"].ToString().Replace(".", "") + " " + dr["workerID"].ToString();

strPrimarySmtpAddress = dr["firstName"].ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "") + "." + dr["lastName"].ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "") + i.ToString() + strSMTPDomain;
}

//Updating mailbox

DirectorySearcher dSearch;

                dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(deCon);

                //Filtering AccountName with Database Domain 
                dSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + strSamAccountName + ")";
                SearchResult sResult = dSearch.FindOne();
                if (sResult != null)    //Check if the Account is available
                {
                    DirectoryEntry deToUpdate = sResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmployeeNumber))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["employeeNumber"].Value = strEmployeeNumber;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nEmployee Number: " + strEmployeeNumber;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmployeeType))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["employeeType"].Value = strEmployeeType;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nEmployee Type: " + strEmployeeType;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strGivenName))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["givenName"].Value = strGivenName;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nFirst Name: " + strGivenName;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSurName))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["sn"].Value = strSurName;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nLast Name:" + strSurName;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTitle))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["title"].Value = strTitle;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nTitle: " + strTitle;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCompany))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["company"].Value = strCompany;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nCompany: " + strCompany;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strDepartment))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["department"].Value = strDepartment;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nDepartment: " + strDepartment;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strBUDesc))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value = strBUDesc;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nBusiness Unit: " + strBUDesc;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strStreetAddress))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["streetAddress"].Value = strStreetAddress;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nAddress: " + strStreetAddress;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strLocation))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["l"].Value = strLocation;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nCity: " + strLocation;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strState))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["st"].Value = strState;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nState:" + strState;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPostalCode))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["postalCode"].Value = strPostalCode;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nZip Code: " + strPostalCode;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCountry))
                    {
                        deToUpdate.Properties["c"].Value = strCountry;
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nCountry/Region:" + strCountry + "";
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strExpiryDate))
                    {
                        DateTime dtExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strExpiryDate).AddDays(1);

                        deToUpdate.Properties["accountExpires"].Value = Convert.ToString((Int64)dtExpiryDate.ToFileTime());
                        strToDisplay = strToDisplay + "\r\nExpiry Date:" + strExpiryDate + "";
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strExtensionAttribute1))
                        deToUpdate.Properties["extensionAttribute1"].Value = strExtensionAttribute1;    //Update Company Code
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strExtensionAttribute2))
                        deToUpdate.Properties["extensionAttribute2"].Value = strExtensionAttribute2;    //Update Location Code
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strExtensionAttribute3))
                        deToUpdate.Properties["extensionAttribute3"].Value = strExtensionAttribute3;    //Update Job Title Code
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strExtensionAttribute4))
                        deToUpdate.Properties["extensionAttribute4"].Value = strExtensionAttribute4;    //Update Management Level Code
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strExtensionAttribute8))
                        deToUpdate.Properties["extensionAttribute8"].Value = strExtensionAttribute8;    //Update Sup Org Code
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strExtensionAttribute10))
                        deToUpdate.Properties["extensionAttribute10"].Value = strExtensionAttribute10;    //Update Department Code
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strExtensionAttribute13))
                        deToUpdate.Properties["extensionAttribute13"].Value = strExtensionAttribute13;    //Update Sup Org

                        }
                        catch (Exception exObj)
                        {
                            WriteToErrorLog("Error while updating Manager details.\n", " Emp AD ID: " + strAlias + "; Manager ID: " + strManager, "Application Exception");
                            WriteToErrorLog("Error while updating Manager (" + strManager + ") details of the Employee (" + strAlias + ").\n", "Message: " + exObj.Message + ";\n Method Name: " + exObj.TargetSite, "Application Exception");
                        }
                    }

                    deToUpdate.CommitChanges();

                    WriteToLog("Account updation succeeded...", "AD Attributes: " + strToDisplay);
                }
else
                {
                    WriteToLog("Account creation/updation failed...", "AD Attributes: " + strToDisplay);
                    strStatusCode = "0";
                    strStatusDesc = "Account Creation failed.";
                }
```

Comment: Yes, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your swift response, jdv. I'm updating the post with the code snippet.